# How to make google maps coordinates works on specific country. - Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, maps, google-maps-markers

I am android developer, and i am working on application such as Uber, Careem, etc.

I have a functionality using the google map, to let the user to set his own marker on particular confidantes.

The problem here is my application is just works on Saudi Arabia only and Jeddah city to be exact. and i am not support any other countries or city expect the above.

I need a solution when the user drop down his marker to display a pop up or something telling him that we are not support this area yet.

Is there any solution.

Thanks,

Comment: I need a solution when the user drop down his marker on invalid coordinates , a popup message something will be displayed telling him that we are not support this area yet.

Comment: I think you have to get the longitude and latitude for jadda center * jadda distance now you have jadda distance... now if user outside this location you pop up your msg... it's not a professional solution i suppose. But it may help you

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Get ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code for this device (or null if not available)
 * @param context Context reference to get the TelephonyManager instance from
 * @return country code or null
 */
public static String getUserCountry(Context context) {
    try {
        final TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager= (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        final String simCountry = mTelephonyManager.getSimCountryIso();
        if (simCountry != null && simCountry.length() == 2) { // SIM country code is available
            return simCountry.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
        }
        else if (mTelephonyManager.getPhoneType() != TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA) { // device is not 3G (would be unreliable)
            String networkCountry = mTelephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso();
            if (networkCountry != null && networkCountry.length() == 2) { // network country code is available
                return networkCountry.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }
    return null;
}
```